# How to filter the correct orders with MySQL (One order contains many lines)

Tags: php, sql, mysql, select

I have to filter orders which do not have a specific product.

It is simple, but the problem is that every order could have many lines, containing different products.

Here is an example of my data:

```
ID | Product | Customer      | Quantidy | Date
 1 | Apple   | Alex Sorensen | 3        | 17.4.2009
 2 | Orange  | Alex Sorensen | 1        | 17.4.2009
 3 | Lime    | Alex Sorensen | 4        | 17.4.2009
 4 | Apple   | Fred Jonsson  | 1        | 30.5.2010
 5 | Lime    | Fred Jonsson  | 7        | 30.5.2010
ect...
```

Lines with the same `date` and the same `customer` are for the same order.

How can I find all the orders which do not have (for example) `Orange` in their order?

---

My own (not working) MySQL-code:

```
SELECT o.ID, k.Customer, o.Quantidy, p.Product, o.Date
FROM Products p, Orders o, Customers c
WHERE p.ID = o.ID
AND k.Customer = o.Customer
AND p.Product NOT IN ('Orange')
GROUP BY o.Date
ORDER BY o.ID DESC
```

The problem is, that even though I don't want "Alex Sorensen's" order, because it contains oranges, I get his other lines without the one containing "Orange".

I need an SQL-code to give me "Fred Jonsson"s and the other orders, that don't have oranges in the order.

Comment: I'm having troubles understanding your model. You join `products` on `p.id = o.id`. Does this mean that you have an `Apple` with `id=1` and another one with `id=4`?

Comment: "p.ID = o.ID" was a mistake, it should be "p.Product = o.Product". I translated and simplified the code from other lenguage, that's way is so bad.

Comment: Is your `p.Product = o.Product` the same `p.Product` that you are selecting (does it actually say `'Orange'` or is it an id for `Orange`)?

Comment: Yes they(p.Product = o.Product) are the same. It is the "id" for the "Orange"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT o.ID, c.Customer, o.Quantity, p.Product, o.Date
FROM Products p, Orders o, Customers c
WHERE p.product = o.product
AND c.Customer = o.Customer
AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM Orders o2
                 WHERE o2.product = 'Orange'
                 AND o2.customer = o.customer
                 AND o2.date = o.date
               )
```

---

Try to use explicit join syntax by the way, it will make reading your queries easier once you are used to it:

```
SELECT o.ID, c.Customer, o.Quantity, p.Product, o.Date
FROM Orders o
JOIN Products p ON ( p.product = o.product )
JOIN Customers c ON ( c.Customer = o.Customer )
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM Orders o2
                   WHERE o2.product = 'Orange'
                   AND o2.customer = o.customer
                   AND o2.date = o.date
                 )
```

Another approach is to use a `Left Join` and check for `NULL`:

```
SELECT o.ID, c.Customer, o.Quantity, p.Product, o.Date
FROM Orders o
JOIN Products p ON ( p.product = o.product )
JOIN Customers c ON ( c.Customer = o.Customer )
LEFT JOIN Orders o2 ON (     o2.product = 'Orange'
                         AND o2.customer = o.customer
                         AND o2.date = o.date
                       )
WHERE o2.Id IS NULL
```

You will have to try which one performs better.

Comment: I used the first one! 
First I got only one result, but when I added: "GROUP BY o.Date
ORDER BY o.ID DESC" to the end, I got all OK. THANKS!!!!!

Comment: Thanks for giving me so many examples, it helps for the future!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 p.Product NOT IN ('Orange')
```

to

```
k.Customer NOT IN (select DISTINCT Customer from Products where Product= 'Orange')


SELECT o.ID, k.Customer, o.Quantidy, p.Product, o.Date
FROM Products p, Orders o, Customers c
WHERE p.ID = o.ID
AND k.Customer = o.Customer
AND k.Customer NOT IN (select DISTINCT Customer from Products where Product= 'Orange')
GROUP BY o.Date
ORDER BY o.ID DESC
```

Comment: The table `Products` does not seem to have a `Customer`-column (and I'd not expect it to have one). You do not consider the `Date`, which groups orders either.

Comment: Yes, "Products" does not have customer. 
"You do not consider the Date, which groups orders either." -> Sorry I don't understand, but I tried to group it by date, but it does not work.